# Excel CSV ending up all on one line

Tags: python, regex, text, expression

I'm looking for help in understanding why my name separator script isn't working. I am working through 'Automate the Boring Stuff With Python' and had the opportunity to test some things out at work today. I recognize this probably not the most efficient solution, but I'm trying to put my learning to work.

**The Goal**
I have an excel file with first and last names in a single cell. I need to separate these into two cells, one for first name and one for last name.

**The Process**

1. I began my saving the excel file as a .csv to then open in a text editor.
2. Used regular expressions to find the full name, grouping first and last names separately. (see the code in link provided)
3. I copy the raw .csv text to the clipboard using pyperclip (I don't know how to read from files yet.)
4. I extract the name data using the regex.
5. I run a for loop which creates a string with first name + ',' + last name + ',' so that excel will put the first and last names in different cells.
6. I want to end each firstName,lastName, pair with a new line so that my .csv file looks like:
   firstname,lastname,
   firstname2,lastname2,
   etc...

I'm getting stuck on the last step. My for loop gets the firstname,lastname, pairs correct, but when I paste from the clipboard, the newline characters are not inserted. Everything is pasted as one huge string. Since I'm appending a new line character each cycle, shouldn't it paste everything on separate lines? Please help me understand what I'm missing!

Here is a link to my script: https://github.com/RNGeezus/name-separator/blob/master/name_separator.py

Here is what my .csv file looks like (recreated with dummy names to protect peopel's privacy):
[my sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeNk3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Turns out I needed each pair to be followed by a `\r\n`. I was doing carriage returns, but no newlines. Doh!